# how to get names and types of every object of a swf file?

Tags: flash, actionscript, mfc, activex

If I have a swf file, is it possible to retrieve object names and types (some kind of reflection) somehow?

Best regards

Comment: which version of actionscript in particular?

Comment: hm, well it can be all of them. i only have swf files, not any information about as version

Answer (score 1):

There is some good "little" discussion of reflection (or introspection) in ActionScript 3 [here](http://www.cflex.net/showfiledetails.cfm?objectid=580&channelid=1). It takes advantage of the special function `describeType` found in the `flash.utils` namespace. Which when passed an object reference, will return XML describing that object's structure. In particular, we are able to know for each propert of the object:

1. the name of the property
2. access rights (public, private, protected,etc)
3. the datatype of the property.

but this solution might possibly only work is you have the source (.fla).

**Another**, much more detailed and authoritative discussion on the matter of introspection in ActionScript [is here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=usingas_8.html).

Hope this helps, or points you somewhere.

Well, for the case of only `swf`, you might have to do some manual introspection by say loading the file into a flash ide or some other tool. Check the [discussion here](http://www.edzis.com/2009/01/as3-preloaders-flashdevelop/), it shows something like it.

Comment: but if i don't have fla ( only swf ) it does not work, right?